# How to set Exposure Times longer than 1 second for a WebCam with Python

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to experiment with different exposure times for a ZWO-ASI120MM webcam
using Python and the OpenCV package.
So far I had no problem to set the exposure times to sub-second values by using:

```
...
import cv2
import sys 

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE, ET)
...
```

for ET = -13, .. -5, .. 0

I would like however to be able to set exposures for several seconds (e.g. 20 sec) with
no success (the ZWO-ASI120MM webcam enables exposure times of 64 μs to 1000 s).

Is there a way to do so? Perhaps with a different Python package (other than OpenCV)?

Thanks for any consideration,

Romi

Comment: Maybe the camera or the driver doesn't support that. I dont know about any openCV limitations at that point.

Comment: According to the manual, the sensor itself allows exposure times up to 2000s. Which OS do you use?

Comment: Hi Micka, I use Windows10 and Python3.6

Comment: Try the ZWO ASI library: https://github.com/python-zwoasi/python-zwoasi and https://github.com/python-zwoasi/python-zwoasi/blob/master/zwoasi/examples/zwoasi_demo.py

Comment: Tried this before. Judging from the number of errors I get, this is way above my (limited) programming skills...

Comment: then take multiple frames and sum/average them. mind the `dtype`. see if you can get raw frames (that need debayering). if not, you might need to take care of gamma-mapping (remove the mapping to work with linear values).